Adapt an existing range type to be c++20 ranges compatible without changing it
My objective is to take some of the Unreal Engine types and make them possible to use with c++20 ranges. I started with TArray I figured it would be the easiest. It is essentailly a std::vector, stored contiguously etc. So in all it can easily be represented with this:
template <typename T, typename A = int>
struct TArray {
    T* GetData() const;
    size_t Num() const;
};

I have basically made a wrapper for this that looks a bit like:
        template <template <typename, typename> typename TCont, typename T, typename TAlloc>
        class rangified_array
        {
        public:
            using ue_container = TCont<T, TAlloc>;

            using value_type             = T;
            using allocator_type         = TAlloc;
            ...

            rangified_array(ue_container& container)
                : m_container{container}
            {
            }

    ...

I will put the full code at the end of the question. You can also play with the toy example here: https://godbolt.org/z/EEEzPWeG7
Basically i seem to have a fully compatible range array, it works with std::range algorithms. It passes checks such as:
using r_t = decltype(make_range(tarr));
static_assert(std::sentinel_for<r_t::iterator, r_t::iterator>);
static_assert(std::ranges::range<r_t>);

But when i use it like this:
auto t = make_range(tarr) | v::transform([](auto i) { return i + 1;}); 

I get a nice big failure, i don't meet the constraints for the range adapter operator.
Gcc suggests:
ranges:955:5: note: constraints not satisfied
ranges: In substitution of 'template<class _Self, class _Range>  requires (__is_range_adaptor_closure<_Self>) && (__adaptor_invocable<_Self, _Range>) constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::operator|(_Range&&, _Self&&) [with _Self = std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Transform, foo()::<lambda(auto:10)> >; _Range = detail::rangified<TArray<int>, int, int>]':
<source>:201:77:   required from here
  201 |         auto t = make_range(tarr) | v::transform([](auto i) { return i + 1;});
      |                                                                             ^
ranges:914:13:   required for the satisfaction of '__adaptor_invocable<_Self, _Range>' [with _Self = std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Transform, foo::._anon_113>; _Range = detail::rangified<TArray<int, int>, int, int>]
ranges:915:9:   in requirements  [with _Adaptor = std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Transform, foo::._anon_113>; _Args = {detail::rangified<TArray<int, int>, int, int>}]

I cannot find any documentation about these constraints. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
Full code incoming
#include <ranges>

template <typename T, typename A = int>
struct TArray {

    T* GetData() const;
    size_t Num() const;

};

    
    namespace detail
    {
        // Currently only the TArray is supported. If you need to range adapt something else you can add the
        // specialisation below.

        template <typename TCont, typename T, typename TAlloc>
        class rangified;

       struct sentinal
       {
       };

        template <bool is_const, typename T>
        class TArrayIterator
        {
        public:
            TArrayIterator() = default;

            explicit TArrayIterator(const T* p, const T* end)
                : m_p{const_cast<T*>(p)}, m_end{end} {}

            explicit TArrayIterator(T* p, const T* end)
                requires (!is_const)
                : m_p{p}, m_end{end} {}

            using value_type        = T;
            using element_type      = T;
            using iterator_category = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;

            T*              operator->() const { return m_p; }
            T&              operator*() const { return *m_p; }
            T&              operator[](size_t p) const { return *(m_p + p); }
            TArrayIterator& operator++()
            {
                ++m_p;
                return *this;
            }

            TArrayIterator operator++(int)
            {
                TArrayIterator out = *this;
                ++(*this);
                return out;
            }

            TArrayIterator& operator--()
            {
                --m_p;
                return *this;
            }

            TArrayIterator operator--(int)
            {
                TArrayIterator out = *this;
                --(*this);
                return out;
            }

            TArrayIterator& operator+=(size_t i)
            {
                m_p += i;
                return *this;
            }

            TArrayIterator& operator-=(size_t i)
            {
                m_p -= i;
                return *this;
            }


friend bool operator==(TArrayIterator lhs, sentinal) {
    return lhs.m_p == lhs.m_end;
}

friend bool operator==(sentinal, TArrayIterator rhs ) {
    return rhs.m_p == rhs.m_end;
}
            friend auto operator<=>(TArrayIterator, TArrayIterator) = default;
            friend bool operator==(TArrayIterator, TArrayIterator) = default;
            friend std::ptrdiff_t operator-(TArrayIterator lhs, TArrayIterator rhs) { return lhs.m_p - rhs.m_p; }
            friend TArrayIterator operator+(TArrayIterator lhs, int rhs) { return TArrayIterator{lhs.m_p + rhs}; }
            friend TArrayIterator operator-(TArrayIterator lhs, int rhs) { return TArrayIterator{lhs.m_p - rhs}; }
            friend TArrayIterator operator+(int lhs, TArrayIterator rhs) { return TArrayIterator{lhs + rhs.rhs}; }

        private:
            T* m_p = nullptr;
            const T* m_end = nullptr;
        };

        template <template <typename, typename> typename TCont, typename T, typename TAlloc>
        class rangified_array
        {
        public:
            using ue_container = TCont<T, TAlloc>;

            using value_type             = T;
            using allocator_type         = TAlloc;
            using size_type              = std::size_t;
            using difference_type        = std::ptrdiff_t;
            using reference              = T&;
            using const_reference        = const T&;
            using pointer                = T*;
            using const_pointer          = const T*;
            using iterator               = TArrayIterator<false, T>;
            using const_iterator         = TArrayIterator<true, T>;
            using reverse_iterator       = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
            using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

            rangified_array(ue_container& container)
                : m_container{container}
            {
            }

            const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator{m_container.GetData(), m_container.GetData() +  + m_container.Num()}; }
            const_iterator end() const { 
                auto last = m_container.GetData() + m_container.Num();
                return const_iterator{last, last };
            }

            iterator begin() { return iterator{
                m_container.GetData(), m_container.GetData()  + m_container.Num()}; 
                }
            iterator end() { 
                auto last = m_container.GetData() + m_container.Num();
                return iterator{last, last };}

        private:


            ue_container& m_container;
        };

        // This provides a specialisation for the const and non const TArray overloads
        template <typename T, typename TAlloc>
        class rangified<TArray<T, TAlloc>, T, TAlloc> : public rangified_array<TArray, T, TAlloc>
        {
            using rangified_array<TArray, T, TAlloc>::rangified_array;
        };

        template <typename TUeComponent>
        struct ue_underlying_types;

        template <typename T, typename TAlloc>
        struct ue_underlying_types<TArray<T, TAlloc>>
        {
            using container_type = TArray<T, TAlloc>;
            using value_type     = T;
            using allocator_type = TAlloc;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct is_range_adapter_supported : public std::false_type
        {
        };

        template <typename T, typename TAlloc>
        struct is_range_adapter_supported<TArray<T, TAlloc>> : public std::true_type
        {
        };

        template <typename T>
        constexpr inline bool is_range_adapter_supported_v = is_range_adapter_supported<T>::value;

    }

    template <typename TUeContainer>
        requires detail::is_range_adapter_supported_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<TUeContainer>>>
    auto make_range(TUeContainer&& arr)
    {
        using T = detail::ue_underlying_types<std::remove_reference_t<TUeContainer>>;
        using R = detail::rangified<typename T::container_type, typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>;
        return R{arr};
    }


A fast patch would be auto TArray::to_span()-> std::span<T>;. Now you can call to_span() member function whenever you need something with the elements. But  making it a friend free function or an explicit  conversion operator might be more convenient.

@Red.Wave good suggestion, but I cannot modify the ue code


I get a nice big failure, I don't meet the constraints for the range adapter operator.

You are correct.
Note [range.refinements] p6:

The viewable_range concept specifies the requirements of a range type that can be converted to a view safely.

Such a conversion takes place when e.g. your range gets wrapped in std::views::all, which happens because of std::ranges::transform_view's deduction guide.
Your rangifed_array satisifes most requirements, but fails at this:

(!view<remove_cvref_t<T>> &&
    (is_lvalue_reference_v<T> ||
        (movable<remove_reference_t<T>> && !is-initializer-list<T>))


Either your rangified_array needs to movable (which it isn't because it's not assignable because you store a reference), or you need to pass things as an lvalue:
auto t = v::transform(r, add_1);

See Compiler Explorer. All compilers allow this (after removing your rhs.rhs typo).
Always having to do the latter is pretty dumb, so just don't store a reference and make your class more like a span.
In fact, I don't really get why you don't just add a conversion from TArray to std::span.
If you desperately want your own type, you can store a pointer instead of a reference and make your type assignable that way.

Amazing, both the answer and that the corresponding error is so hard to parse. I didn't think of the span, idea, but that is great. I will still need some of these concepts when I do the range for the TMap and others
